# Update a row if a column value is not the same on other table

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb

So here's the catch, i have two table. Let's assume the one table names servers and the other one is users.

**Server:**

[image]

**User:**

[image]

So as you can see on the users table the server_ip is not the same within the server_ip of servers table. So how can i update is_connected to 0 if the server_ip on users table is not the same on servers table based on its server_name. Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and include all information as _text_, _not_ images.  And then tell us which database you are using.

Comment: What have you tried fo this problem?

Comment: @Dani it's for authentication.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table2
set a.is_connected = 0
from table2 a
join table1 b
on (a.server_name = b.server_name)
where b.server_name is null
```

try this code. this will update all the rows with the ip of server table.

Comment: Thank you. But is_connected on users table must be the one who will be set to = 0 where server_ip of users table is not the same of server_ip on servers table based on its server name

Comment: Thank you for the modified version, still not suites the code. What i mean is the servers table has server_name, server_ip & users table has server_name, server_ip, is_connected. So what i want to do is if the server_ip is not the same as server_ip on servers table then we set the is_connected to 0 in users table. But we must select the server_name of from users table to server_name from servers table so we can check the server_ip of servers table if it doesn't match the server_ip on users table so we can update the is_connected of users table to 0.